# Connect CPLEX OPL model with MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, cplex, opl

I want to use the data from an external MySQL database in a CPLEX OPL model.

As far as I understand this should be possible with OPL's [DBConnection](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllangref/topics/opl_langref_db_init_supported.html) and ODBC. For the construction of the connection string I found [this information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-without-dsn.html).

Now I started a test project 'test.mod':

```
{string} names = ...;

execute DISPLAY {
    writeln("names: ");
        for (var n in names)
            writeln(n);
}
```

and 'test.dat':

```
DBConnection db("odbc", "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Driver};SERVER=*ip*:*port*;DATABASE=*dbname*;USER=*user*;PASSWORD=*pw*;OPTION=3;");

names from DBRead(db, "SELECT name FROM customer");
```

At the moment I am getting this error for the DBConnection line: "Data parsing error: syntax error, unexpected (identifier), expecting from or to."

Now I wonder if it is even possible the connect CPLEX/OPL and MySQL? Or if I am maybe missing something to enable ODBC or if my syntax of the connection string is incorrect.

Comment: Which cplex version do you use ?

Comment: I am using version 12.8.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You may find the list of databases that used to be supported in OPL at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/tr/SSSA5P_12.6.2/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/working_environment/topics/opl_working_env_db.html

But since version 12.7 you need to find another way.

A workaround is to use IloOplExec as explained in https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=d7c20a69-8b24-49d6-b439-a9b381539637&ps=25

Comment: Thank you very much! Also your list helped me a lot: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-opl-alex-fleischer